# Decimals ignored in numbers with Exponent

Tags: math, language-agnostic, decimal, scientific-notation, exponent

Why are my decimals ignored when I have `e` (Exponent) inside it? When I type `53e6`, it gives the exact same result as `53.e6` (`53000000`). I would expect the output of the latter to be `53.000000` or just `53`... A note would be that `5.3e6` is different. I'm not sure why this happens.

I tested this in C, C++, Java, JavaScript, and Python—they all give the same result. Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
console.log("53e6:", 53e6);
console.log("53.e6:", 53.e6);
console.log("53e6 equals 53.e6?", 53e6 === 53.e6);
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Why do you expect `53.e6` to be `53.000000`? `53.` means `53.0`, which is mathematically the same as `53`; and `e6` means `*10^6`, i.e. `*1000000`. So `53.e6` is `53.0 * 1000000` which is of course `53000000`.

Comment: So `e` is then an operator? Because I thought it just got rendered.

Comment: `e` is not an operator; it is a part of numerical notation, the scientific notation.  A number such as `123.456e7` would mean `123.456*10^7` which is the same as `1234560000`.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation